# aws s3 search sub-folders containing one specific file

Tags: amazon-s3

I understand that s3 does not have "folder" but I will still use the term to illustrate what I am looking for.

I have this folder structure in s3:
    my-bucket/folder-1/file-named-a
    my-bucket/folder-2/...
    my-bucket/folder-3/file-named-a
    my-bucket/folder-4/...

I would like to find all folders containing "file-named-a", so folder-1 and folder-3 in above example will be returned. I only need to search the "top level" folders under my-bucket. There could be tens of thousands of folders to search. How to construct the ListObjectsRequest to do that?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: I doubt there's a straightforward way. Do the folder names follow a pattern?

Comment: TJ, there is no pattern on the folder names, they are all UUIDs. I am trying to use "file-named-a" as a flag to indicate another processor that the folder is ready for processing.

Answer (score 1):

An Amazon S3 bucket can be listed (`ListBucket()`) to view its contents, and this API call can be limited by a `Prefix`. However, it is not possible to put a wildcard within the prefix.

Therefore, you would need to **retrieve the entire bucket listing**, looking for these files. This would require repeated calls if there are a large number of objects.

Example: [Listing Keys Using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html)

Comment: Thank you John. I think that is the best I can do for now.